# How to properly iterate over QT's STL style vector

Tags: c++, qt, iterator

I am trying to iterate over a vector.

The vector memory is initialized to hold 10 elements max.

Now I assigned first 3 elements and try to print them using STL style iterator in QT.

```
#include <QDebug>

int main() {
    QVector<int> vv(10);
        vv[0] = 1;
        vv[1] = 2;
        vv[2] = 3;
        QVector<int>::iterator itt;
        for (itt = vv.begin(); itt != vv.end(); ++itt) {
            qDebug() << vv.at(*itt);
        }
}
```

the output is weird:
It's not 1 2 3
instead its 2 3 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Why is this happening ? Can you someone explain this please.

Comment: `*itt` is the element of the vector.  It should just be `qDebug() << *itt;`

Comment: @NathanOliver...That's the solution. Thanks. May I know how to traverse only till the first 3 elements ? the Java style iterator has Hasnext() function which does the job.

Comment: The problem is your vector doesn't have 3 elements, it has 10. `QVector<int> vv(10);` says give me a `QVector` that has 10 default elements in it.  If you want it to only have 3 then you need `QVector<int> vv(3);`

Comment: Why don't you want to use the simple c++11 syntax for(auto myelement : myvector) ?

Answer (score 4):

As @NathanOliver pointed out you have two problems:

1. `*itt` already is the element of the vector, so it should just be `qDebug() << *itt;`.
2. If you create a vector of a certain size for each vector index a default element of the type the vector holds is created. That is also the reason why you can't use container classes like `QVector` for types without a default constructor. In your case the vector is filled with 1s on creation because 1 is the default value of an `int`. You then just override the first 3 values.

I have some further concerns regarding your code:

1. If you expect your vector to only hold as much values as you add, why even provide a length of the vector? `QVector` is perfectly capable of managing its storage itself. You just use `QVector::append` or `QVector::operator<<` to add values and your vector has exactly as many values as you added.
2. Why use STL style iterators in this case anyway? `QVectorIterator` provides such convenient methods to iterate over a vector. They also make the code much more readable.

If I were you I would have written the code as follows:

```
#include <QVector>
#include <QDebug>

int main() {
    QVector<int> numbers = QVector<int>() << 1 << 2 << 3;
    QVectorIterator<int> itNumbers(numbers);
    while (itNumbers.hasNext()) {
        qDebug() << itNumbers.next();
    }
}
```